# Disabling and enabling Textbox based on selection of RadioButton But It's working Once,again i click for enable it's not working,please help me

Tags: jquery

this is my View Page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#B_StopTube').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                $("#Dub_StopTubeLength").prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else 
            {
                $("#Dub_StopTubeLength").removeprop("disabled");
            }
        })
    });
  </script> 
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.B_StopTube, false)&nbsp;No
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.B_StopTube, false)&nbsp;Yes
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dub_StopTubeLength)
    </td>​
```

and this my model:

```
    public bool B_StopTube { get; set; }
    public double Dub_StopTubeLength { get; set; }
```

it's working at first time if i change the selection of radiobutton it's not enabling textbox.i am not getting idea how to solve this problem please help me...i am a new MVC programmer...

Comment: add a jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo use `removeProp()` instead of `removeprop()`

Use

```
$("#Dub_StopTubeLength").removeProp("disabled");
```

Your code can be improved as

```
$('#B_StopTube').change(function () {
    $("#Dub_StopTubeLength").prop("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'))
})
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, OP has used `.removeprop`

Comment: Yeah i just noticed that, but removeProp() also work in this context right.?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function () {
    $('#B_StopTube').change(function () {
     if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
       $("#Dub_StopTubeLength").attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
     else 
     {
       $("#Dub_StopTubeLength").removeAttr('disabled');
     }
    })
    });
```